# Does SoundCloud provide full dataset dumps of the API?

Tags: api, dataset, soundcloud

My research team has been carefully exploring the SoundCloud API, and has obtained a client ID. However, does SoundCloud provide dumps with complete sets of data? For example, [Jamendo](http://www.jamendo.com) has [nightly dumps](http://developer.jamendo.com/en/wiki/NewDatabaseDumps) of most of their track-related data and [Magnatune](http://magnatune.com) has a [full dump of all track data](http://magnatune.com/info/api) updated whenever there is a change. Does SoundCloud provide any similar full dumps of its data?

Comment: I would really appreciate a yes or no from the SoundCloud official support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not provide this kind of dump of our data.

Comment: I sent an e-mail a couple weeks ago to api@soundcloud.com asking about dumps, but got no response, even though I sent the e-mail again. What would be the best way to reach SoundCloud officially to request data for a special research collaboration?